Why do I need to close the stream after writing to it in c#?
I am trying to write something to a new file at the end of a C# program:
The following statement does not work.
feedMessage.WriteTo(new FileStream(output, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write));

It only works if I manually dispose the output stream.
await using (var outputStream = new FileStream(output, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write)) {
    feedMessage.WriteTo(outputStream);
}

Why do I need to dispose the stream? Don't all resources get automatically disposed at the end of program?
I come from a C++ background where all resources are released as the variable goes out of scope, so I don't understand how resource management work with garbage collection.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52644065/does-c-sharp-app-exit-automatically-dispose-managed-resources

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29534/IDisposable-What-Your-Mother-Never-Told-You-About

Stream.Dispose() implicitly calls Flush() and Close()

"The following statement does not work". Saying that something doesn't work is never a sufficient problem description. You ALWAYS need to provide FULL and CLEAR explanation, including EXACTLY what you expect to happen and what does happen.

"from a C++ background" - so you never freed a pointer, closed a file or connection?  Really?

It is enogh to call Close() method. Without Close you want to do half work and ask why it is not finished.

In C++, resources are obtained in the constructor and released in the destructor. There is never a need to explicitly close a file or a connection in the application code.

Dispose method will not be called by the .NET. The normal practice is to call Dispose from the finalizer. The finalizer will be called during the GC run. Now, there can be a situation when there were no GC runs during the application lifetime. Will the finalizer be called during the termination?
From the https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/finalizers#remarks:

Whether or not finalizers are run as part of application termination is specific to each implementation of .NET. When an application terminates, .NET Framework makes every reasonable effort to call finalizers for objects that haven't yet been garbage collected, unless such cleanup has been suppressed (by a call to the library method GC.SuppressFinalize, for example). .NET 5 (including .NET Core) and later versions don't call finalizers as part of application termination.

So, there are no guarantees that the finalizer will be called. The only way to ensure that stream was flushed to file is to dispose it yourself.

It is interesting what happens with open file if it is not automatically closed? Corrupted filesystem or file changes are ignored (existing only in cache)?

You just create a FileLock and the file can't be accessed by another process/program?

@i486 the OS will close the file, and the file system is not going to be corrupted. but everything that wasn't yet passed to the OS (like the content of the internal Stream buffer) will not be written to file.

The finalizer should only release unmanaged resources, not call Dispose(). A common pattern is to have a protected virtual void Dispose(bool explicitDispose) method, that always releases unmanaged resources, but only releases managed resources if explicitDispose is true.


Don't all resources get automatically disposed at the end of program?

No. Objects implementing IDisposable is not automatically disposed. You have to do that yourself, either explicitly, or implicitly by using using myDisposable. So if your program relies on calling dispose to flush data you have to call it yourself.
You have a choice between using declarations and statements. Declarations might be more familiar if you are used to C++.

// declaration
using var outputStream = new FileStream(...);

// statement
using (var outputStream = new FileStream(...)){

}

The OS will release any OS resources on process termination, like memory and file handles, but this does not guarantee that that your writes have been flushed.
There are also finalizers that should be used to ensure unmanaged resources are released. Finalizers can be a bit complicated, but the short version is that they are a safety net, and should not be relied upon.

This question should be split into two.
The first is: 
Should an instance of IDisposable always be manually disposed?
The answer to it is: 
In most cases, yes. A memory leakage will occur if you don't dispose them manually.
In your case, you write one or more file, thus creating one or more FileStream instances, then I guess the application is terminated, afterwards the memory fragments of the terminated application is taken care of by the operating system.The leakage caused by limited quantity of FileStream instance is low and eliminated by operating system very soon so it's not severe enough to be observed.
In short words, while the application is still alive, it's GC's job to collect garbage and free memory of unused references, it's your job to tell GC that an instance of IDisposable can be collected. After the application is terminated, it's the operating system's job to finalize the memory used by that application.
Of course Dispose() in IDisposable does more than marking itself can be collected by GC. Actually a class implementing IDisposable usually suggests that there are unmanaged resources or IDisposable fields or properties used inside the class, which they get disposed or dealt with insiide Dispose().
The second is:
Why the text written to FileStream not being actually written to the file without disposing the stream but got written to the file if disposed?
The answer is:
Some Stream like FileStream has a buffering mechanism inside. The content written into a FileStream won't be written to the actual file unless the buffer is full or Flush() is called. This is totally resonable due to performance consideration.
An call to Close() or Dispose() implies a call to Flush() and that's why you got your content written into the file after you use the using pattern.
